# how to use bootstrap framework

Tags: sharepoint-server, responsive

I downloaded bootstrap framework using this [link](https://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/112845)
available on codeplex.

I have created empty sharepoint project in visual studio 2013. Then manually added bootstrap related files in Layout folder. See my project files in visual studio below

[image]

Now i went to my page and selected site settings. Then i selected Look and feel >Master page. But i cannot see bootstrap.master. How can i see that in site settings. I am using sharepoint 2013

**Update1**

My element.xml is as below

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<Module Name="MasterPage" List="116" Url="_catalogs/masterpage">
 <File Path="MasterPage\acme.master" Url="acme.master" />
 <File Path="MasterPage\bootstrap3.master" Url="bootstrap3.master" />
</Module>
```

My module1's element.xml is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
 <Module Name="Module1">
  <File Path="Module1\Mycustom.css" Url="Mycustom.css" />
</Module>
</Elements>
```

Comment: Did you check in the master file and make sure that a major version is available?

Comment: is the elements file correct?

Comment: @PirateEric updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Master Page Gallery, then Publish and Approve the master page.

Try changing XML file as follows

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Module Name="MasterPage" List="116" Url="_catalogs/masterpage">
    <File Path="MasterPage\acme.master" Url="acme.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Level="Published" ReplaceContent="true"/>
    <File Path="MasterPage\bootstrap3.master" Url="bootstrap3.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Level="Published" ReplaceContent="true"/>
    </Module>
</Elements>
```

Comment: when i go to Master page gallery i cannot find bootstrap3 but can find acme.master

Comment: Element.xml has this 
 <File Path="MasterPage\bootstrap3.master" Url="bootstrap3.master" />

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: please help me if you have any ideas

Comment: Its working and i selected bootstrap3.master in master page but dont see any predefined template on site. I checked in bootstrap3.master file and there is something like this <link href="/_catalogs/masterpage/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />    Is this the reason that its not finding this css and not applying any theme. where exactly i should put bootstrap.css.

Comment: I would be too much thankful if you can answer my last question i asked in above comment. Meanwhile i am accepting your answer. Can you also upvote my question because i want to upvote your answer too.

Comment: Sorry didnt get what you meant. The  code i pasted was in bootstrap3.master file. so isnt that in .master page file already or what are you trying to say?

Comment: how can i do that? Sorry i am bothering you

Comment: Based on your project solution structure, those css files are going into the 14 hive.. so one option is to change the link in the master file to point to `_layouts/SharePointProject4/css/bootstrap.css`

Comment: Nope not working but thats ok. You have been too much patient with me.

Comment: I have asked one more question here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136883/bootstrap-theme-not-getting-applied