# Bootstrap theme not getting applied

Tags: sharepoint-server, boot-strap, responsive

This question is in continuation of my previous question asked [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136761/how-to-use-bootstrap-framework/136762?noredirect=1#comment138309_136762)

I can now see bootstrap3.master in my master page gallery. When i see my page it doesnt look like bootstrap theme is appled. I have also change references to bss files as below

[image]

Previously these links were pointing to catalogs folder. I would also be so much thankful if there is any document or steps which i can follow to create responsive site using bootstrap. The [link](https://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/112845) here do not have any instruction for installation which is really bad.

**Update1**

I made changes as said by Dave Tansley in answer
[image]

Also this is how my master page gallery looks but dont see any bootstrap related files like js and css

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things to check:

- Are your JavaScript files actually getting deployed to the file system? Is your "Layouts" folder in your VS solution actually a "Mapped" folder? If not, they won't get copied (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231521.aspx). You can check if they're there, simply by browsing to the location on the filesystem, somewhere like:

  C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15
- Are your paths right? If you're using SharePoint 2013, you'll need an extra "15" in there. Do you also need an initial "/"? For example:

  <script src="/_layouts/15/SharePointProject4/js/blah.js"></script>

Comment: I updated question but not working

Comment: Are you sure you have the paths right? The updated answer has "/Layouts/SharePointProject4/js...", my suggestions was "/_layouts/15/SharePointProject4/...".

Comment: do i do for both css and js files?

Comment: Perfect. Its working. So is this the standard practise to do it? Can you tell me how to add html file and use bootstrap functionality to create page